# Logging in json

Tags: json, logging, log4j

I would like to log messages in a jSon format from within Java. I would like the convenience of professional logging like log4j for hierarchical loggers and method names, but I would also like to output other key-value names in the json object.

I am looking for output simillar to this:

```
{ 'time':'123' , level:'debug', action: 'open',filename:'bla.txt'}

{ 'time':'432' , level:'info', action: 'calculate',result:'353'}
```

If I use log4j and reformat I cannot get the automatic values (timestamp for example) in the same object as the logged values.

Is there a logging framework or plugin to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started using this project
Works great

https://github.com/michaeltandy/log4j-json

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [elf4j-engine](https://github.com/elf4j/elf4j-provider).

JSON and async logging out of the box. JSON pattern is configurable, either minified one-line (default) or pretty print.

**Disclaimer**: I am the developer of elf4j-provider/elf4j-engine